# how to convert multidimensional array to string in idl

Tags: idl-programming-language

I have an array of floats or doubles lets call it foo. When I do

```
size(foo)
```

I get these 5 dimensions

```
2          67       52100           4     3498338
```

I would like to convert it to a string like

```
str="strcture={arr:"+foo+"}"
```

so that I can then do

```
Execute(str)
```

How can I convert `foo` to a string dynamically?

Comment: that's a total of ~10^14 elements - are you sure you want to dump this to string?

Comment: Yes I am saving them to a file. But the question is more general. For a multidimensional array how to convert it to a string dynamically.

Comment: perhaps you just want the SAVE procedure? https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/SAVE.html

Answer (score 1):

I have something to print the declaration of a variable [in my library](https://github.com/mgalloy/mglib/blob/master/src/introspection/mg_variable_declaration.pro):

```
IDL> print, mg_variable_declaration(replicate({a: 0.0, b: 1.0}, 10))
replicate({ A: 0.00000, B: 1.00000 }, 10)
```

It won't get all the data values, though. Just create a variable of the correct type. It might get you part of the way, though.